# Nan::AsyncQueue is failed at runtime

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js-addon

Hi I am learning addon implementation. I am getting the error below.

This error coming from js file:

> vec1.add_number(20,function(err,res)) SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

index.js:

```
var m = require('./');
   var vec1 = new  m.Vector(20, 10, 0); // call to new
   vec1.add_number(20,function(err,res)) // **here is the error pls help to fix**
    {
    if(err)
    console.error(err);
    else
    console.log('Final Result=%d',res);
```

testworker.cc

```
#include<nan.h>
#include  "testWorker.h"
#include<iostream>
void TestWorker::Execute()
{
 std::cout<<"its Execition\n";
 myNumber +=6;
}

void TestWorker::Handleokcallback()
{
std::cout<<"Enter to Handleokcallback\n";
Nan::HandleScope scope;
auto numberjs= Nan::New(myNumber);
v8::local<v8::Value> argv[] ={Nan::Undefined,numberjs};
myCallback->call(2,argv);    
}
```

### Here is the error logs

module.js:435
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: /home/admin1/Desktop/node-addon-tutorial-master/VectorExample/build/Release/myModule.node: undefined symbol: _ZTV10TestWorker
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:435:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object. (/home/admin1/Desktop/node-addon-tutorial-master/VectorExample/bindings.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)

Comment: Please get at least a bit familiar with JS. Also, extract a [mcve], it's important for a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one extra `)` in `function(err,res))` and you're missing `})` at the end.

Here's your code without syntax errors.

```
var m = require('./');
var vec1 = new  m.Vector(20, 10, 0); // call to new
vec1.add_number(20,function(err,res) { // changed ) with {
    if(err)
       console.error(err);
    else
       console.log('Final Result=%d',res);
}); // Added this
```

Comment: please excuse for silly error ..i have one more error can u pls 

module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^
why is this ?

Comment: Hmm, post full stack trace, Its on line 328, You only have 8 here, so, post more code or full stack trace.

Comment: I have the added full error logs .Can you please check it above please help?

Comment: I will take a look when I get home in ~6 hours :). But now it seems an error in your addon itself, I'll probably need to know how you're building it, maybe post your `binding.gyp` so I have more info, and be able to compile the addon myself.

Comment: Thank i was doing build from wrong path it fine now i have runtime error .I have posted fresh question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758230/handleokcallback-is-not-called-result-in-runtime-garbage-value